# Which event handler should I use for DOM manipulation on a lazy loading React site like Instagram?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to write a Chrome Extension that adds little upload buttons to images on profile pages on Instagram. Instagram is a React site that uses XHRs to populate images to the page as the user scrolls down the page.

In my content script, which event handler should my logic be placed, so I can add the buttons?

I tried window.onload, but as expected, it only selects the initial 12 images.

```js
// manifest.json:
{
  "name": "Instagram to Imgur",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Easily upload instagram pics to Imgur",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon_16.png",
    "32": "icons/icon_32.png",
    "48": "icons/icon_48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon_128.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.instagram.com/*"],
      "js": ["scripts/content/domInject.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
}

// domInject.js:
window.onload = function() {
    const imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('FFVAD');

    console.log(imgs.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        console.log(imgs[i].srcset);
        // addButton(imgs[i]);
    }
};
```

Comment: See this answer: [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)

Comment: @wOxxOm - That was really useful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to implement this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
    // Just used the class name i observed as of now. Feel free to replace with a proper tag
    var targetNode = document.getElementsByClassName('cGcGK')[0];

    // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
    var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

    // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
    var callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
        for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
            if (mutation.type == 'childList' && mutation.addedNodes.length>0 ) {
                Array.prototype.forEach.call(mutation.addedNodes, function (node) {
                  if(node.tagName == "img" && node.attr("class") == "FFVAD")
                  {
                    // Add button to node code
                    console.log(node)
                  }
                });
            }
        }
    };

    // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
    var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

    // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
    observer.observe(targetNode, config);
}
```

You can also use [Mutation Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) **DOMNODEInserted** as of now but they are deprecated so not really recommended. Also, they affect further DOM changes performance.

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    img = $(e.target).find("img.FFVAD")
    if(img.length){
      //Add button code
      console.log(img)
    }
});
```

I tried both these approaches in Content js and they seem to work.

Comment: The snippet you suggested didn't work for me, since only the #react-root div is available when the page first loads. But it sent me in the right direction. I had to use a polling approach until the XHRs completed, page structure was formed, etc. Then once the target node was found through polling, I was able to start listening on the target node. This video helped me write the polling bit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hn2zzi_lquA&t=97s